# VBA open url in Firefox and save the website locally

Tags: xml, vba, url, save, mozilla

I created a code in VBA for excel to open a particular website in Firefox (see bellow). I need to open it in FF and not in Explorer becasue for some reason the server of my company shows ONLY a long XML code that wont be shown if opened in IE (dont ask me why).

I have an application developed in Excel and I uwe this code to load the XML file in MOZILA from the server:

```
'Determine the Path to FF executable
 Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 sFFExe = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Firefox.EXE\")
 'Open the URL
  Shell """" & sFFExe & """" & " -new-tab """ & sURL & "", vbHide
```

This code works perfectly. being the variable sURL part of the whole URL.
Afterwards I save manually the web site as XML file.

I am wondering if I can automate this saving file step and run all in the background. ONce I have the XML file in my computer I can go on wiht the rest of my macro extracting data from the XML.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need SendKeys to control Firefox from VBA. There is no library for it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I know about .sendkeys but how do you actually do it. I mean the following looks fine:
'.sendkeys (^S)'
 = CTRL-S (=save)
but what do you write in front ot sendkeys? I was looking at documentation and I found that before send keys the application has to be specified. How do you specify it?

Comment: Make sure that when you call Firefox, it will be the active Window. If you use `vbHide` SendKeys won't work on Firefox. Try with `vbMaximizedFocus`

Comment: Why not just make XHR by the URL, and save response to file, not using any browser at all?

Comment: @foxfire I dont neccesary need this operation to work in the background. this code does not work:

`Dim FFApp As WebBrowser

  Set IEApp = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Firefox.EXE"
 FFApp.Visible = True
FFapp.SendKeys (^s,[12])`


I got it from somewhere in the web. Vba gives error when declaring the webbrowser.

Comment: [Check how SendKeys work, because you are typing it wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-sendkeys-method-excel). You have to use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, getting bit a bit to it.
With mozilla open I send:
`SendKeys "^s", true`
It works. Namely The save file window opens and the name of the file is selected.
But sending more letters do not overwrite the name of the file.

nor can I send three tabs and then enter (save with the proposed name) since three tabs leaves the focus to "SAVE"
`SendKeys "{TAB}", true
    SendKeys "{TAB}", true
    SendKeys "{TAB}", true
    SendKeys "~", true`
I added "true" because in the MS help iwth that parameter is waits for the key to be processed

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was the following code:
For open the url in mozilla:

```
'Determine the Path to FF executable
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sFFExe = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Firefox.EXE\")
'Open the URL
Shell """" & sFFExe & """" & " -new-tab """ & sURL & "", vbHide
```

where sURL is your site www.whatever.com
And now to save the site (without the time between keysends did not wrok well)

```
Sub save_XML_file()
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
SendKeys "^s", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
'here it is not possible to send the key strolkes of a variable. therefore always saving the file ascurrent.txt and afterwads in a third routine copy and renaming the file.

SendKeys "Current.XML", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the waiting time solved the problem.
For the problem of of variable filenames I did not try to insert a variable.
As a workaround I defined the corresponding filenames in an excel-table an copied them to the clipboard each time.
After opening of the 'file save' window I simply send 'Ctrl' + v:

```
    Selection.Copy 'copies filename from actual selected cell into clipboard
    ...
    Application.SendKeys ("^s")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "^v", True
```